# Unable to locate package linux-kernel-devel

Tags: apt

I am pretty sure there are three other links that report the same problem, I am getting

I am following this link to compile my custom Kernel

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile/

> Tools you'll need To start, you will need to install a few packages.
>   The exact commands to install those packages depends on which release
>   you are using:
>
> Hardy (8.04):
>
> sudo apt-get install linux-kernel-devel fakeroot kernel-wedge
>   build-essential

When I try the above packages the fakroot, kernel-wedge, build-essentail all seem to be accesible by terminal except for the linux-kernel-devel.

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-kernel-devel  
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done
E:Unable to locate package linux-kernel-devel
```

I am trying to install Hardy to my ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, So far I tried

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-kernel-devel
```

I even tried to modify the sourcelist and added the universe line to the line below.

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
```

What is that I am missing here? Why is Ubuntu not able to locate the package? I am wired and connected to the internet.

Comment: You should have read the introduction on bold letters that says "this page would need significant cleaning. You may want to refer to [Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) page in Ubuntu wiki instead which is a cleaner and more up-to-date guide to (simple) kernel building"

Comment: @Braiam I did refer to the same doc,but  I need to install lucid,hardy(excluding the linux-kernel-devel) mentioned in the link above for the CRDA packages else it was throwing package crda,crda-wireless not found. That was the reason I had to go back to install the above packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That specific package isn't packaged in Ubuntu 10.04 and up. If you're trying to compile a custom kernel, the correct way to get the prerequisites in Ubuntu 10.04 and later is to run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install fakeroot build-essential crash kexec-tools makedumpfile kernel-wedge
sudo apt-get build-dep linux
sudo apt-get install git-core libncurses5 libncurses5-dev libelf-dev asciidoc binutils-dev
```

Hardy is a completely different version of Ubuntu, and can't be installed to another version. If you need Ubuntu 8.04 (Hardy Heron), you would need to find a copy of it online, download it, then write it to a CD or DVD.

That said, 8.04 is long out of service, and it's recommend to use a newer version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Awesome Ian. I was hoping to hear that the package is deprecated.  I did install 12.X and not the earlier ones, since the doc said that the prerequisite for installing custom kernel is to install hardy and Lucid I was persistent on finding how to do this.